# Azure Service Bus and Javascript Implementation

Tags: javascript, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a Azure Service Bus Topic and I want to receive the messages in realtime on a web page that uses pure Javascript.

I tried this SDK (http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2015/01/26/eventhubs-support-for-azure-servicebus-javascript-sdk.aspx) but when I speed up the sending message not worked well.

I tried too REST API but not worked well too.

Exist any alternative?

Regards

Comment: There is no official Azure Service Bus front-end javascript SDK. Could you share the code that you have written work with Service Bus via REST API?

Comment: @AaronChen-MSFT I tried JQuery GET like this to receive my messages:

$.get("https://<service_bus_name>.servicebus.windows.net/<topic_name>/subscriptions/<subscription_name>/messages/head/", function(data, status) {
    console.log("Data: " + data + " | Status: " + status);
});

Answer (score 0):

It requires an **Authorization** request header to [receive the messages from a queue or subscription via REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/receive-and-delete-message-destructive-read). The value of the header could be `a SAS token` or `a SimpleWebToken acquired from ACS`.

About how to generate a Shared Access Signature (token), you can check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#configuration-for-shared-access-signature-authentication). For request a Token from ACS, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/request-a-token-from-acs).

Comment: Thanks. I read the info that you sent, but already I have some technical questions. How I can develop the Receive and Delete message in Javascript? I can find some JS functional examples/samples

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late reply, but just in case somebody is looking to use **Azure SDK for JS** libraries on a website, you need to convert your code to work inside the browser. You can do this using bundler such as rollup, webpack, parcel, etc. Refer to this [bundling docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/documentation/Bundling.md) to use the `@azure/service-bus` library in the browsers.

High performant version 7.0.0 @azure/service-bus library based on AMQP protocol has been recently published. Refer to the links below.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)